# How to change base url from $fetch in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

In nuxt 2 we could do something like:

nuxt.config.js

```
...
axios : {
   baseURL: 'some url'
}
```

what is the equivalent to that in nuxt3 for `$fetch`?

Comment: Create a reusable composable and use that one instead. This is the Vue3 approach.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings as written in the docs? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch